# ReadyRoll Project: Octopus Deploy - Unable to get DefaultDataPath, DefaultLogPath & DefaultBackupPath

Tags: sql, redgate, readyroll

I am trying to deploy my database using Octopus Deploy and I get the following error,

Could not retrieve a value for DefaultDataPath : Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user"

I have verified all the paths but it still shows me this error.

Comment: Does the Tentacle service have access to the SQL Server instance you're trying to deploy to? If not, you can either change the *Run As* credentials in Windows Services to an account that does, or supply username/password credentials to connect via SQL Server Authentication as described here: https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/RR1/Octopus+Deploy#OctopusDeploy-specifyingDatabaseNameServerSpecifyingtheDatabaseServer/Name(optional)

Comment: By 'Service' you mean the service account that is used for tentacle?

Comment: Indeed, the account that the service is running under.